# Open Explorer and redirect to specific path after SaveFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

I create a simple function to download a file from the URL and then save it to some folder using SaveFileDialog and then the program will open Windows Explorer to the path of the saved file.
but I don't know how to get the last path of the SaveFileDialog

here is my code :

```
Dim path = "myURL"

Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog1.FileName = dgvAttachmentName & dgvFileExtensi
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Using client As New WebClient()

        client.DownloadFile(path, saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/root," & saveFileDialog1.FileName)

    End Using
End If
```

If I use `SaveFileDialog1.FileName`, I get the full path of the File but with a FileName, but I also can't use `replace` to remove the file name from the path because User can change the file name every time they want to save a file.

How to get the path only from the SaveFileDialog then open explorer to that path ?

Comment: Any time you want to perform operations on filenames and paths, I would recommend to see if there is something in `System.IO.Path` that will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
 Dim Path = fi.DirectoryName
```

all together:

```
Dim path = "myURL"

Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog1.FileName = dgvAttachmentName & dgvFileExtensi
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Using client As New WebClient()

        client.DownloadFile(path, saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        
        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim Path = fi.DirectoryName

        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/root," & Path )

    End Using
End If
```

Comment: An alternative is to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName)`, which avoids having to create a FileInfo object.